# Descramble the scrambled text

Tags: cipher

I did something funny.  I took a simple phrase.

```
HELLO, WORLD!
```

I generated all rotations of the string.

```
HELLO, WORLD!
ELLO, WORLD!H
LLO, WORLD!HE
LO, WORLD!HEL
O, WORLD!HELL
, WORLD!HELLO
 WORLD!HELLO,
WORLD!HELLO, 
ORLD!HELLO, W
RLD!HELLO, WO
LD!HELLO, WOR
D!HELLO, WORL
!HELLO, WORLD
```

Then I sorted the strings.

```
 WORLD!HELLO,
!HELLO, WORLD
, WORLD!HELLO
D!HELLO, WORL
ELLO, WORLD!H
HELLO, WORLD!
LD!HELLO, WOR
LLO, WORLD!HE
LO, WORLD!HEL
O, WORLD!HELL
ORLD!HELLO, W
RLD!HELLO, WO
WORLD!HELLO,
```

And I collected the last character of each line.  I got the string:

```
",DOLH!RELLWO "
```

As you can see, it is the original message scrambled.  But this was just an example.  I did the same thing with a much longer message and I got the following string:

```
"DFKDKKWHKAADD  UDD  UUUU LLOOOOIC?CCCC CCCCUU OOOOWWWWWCHMHHHHOOO     "
```

Can you tell me what the message was?

Comment: I only realized after editing out [cryptography] that the edit had previously been reversed. Why do you think this is a cryptographic puzzle? You're not asking us to develop a strategy for how to use encryption, such as public-key cryptography; you're asking us to decipher a string given a known encryption.

Comment: Encryption is cryptography.

Comment: On this site, specifically for tagging, [[tag:cipher]] is the tag used for encryption, and [[tag:cryptography]] means something else.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This procedure is called the [Burrows-Wheeler transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform). It is useful for data compression, because if the starting text contains many identical substrings ("the", "and", ...), then the Burrows-Wheeler transformation will contain many runs of identical characters.

Applying the inverse algorithm on that Wikipedia page, with a suitable guess of the location of the end-of-file marker "|", gives the answer:

`HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?`

Comment: Many thanks for the Wikipedia reference; I'd never heard of this one before and it's a cute and somewhat surprising (to me) result.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is:

```
HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?
```

All of the rotations of the string are:

```
HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?
OW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?H
W MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HO
 MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW
MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW 
UCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW M
CH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MU
H WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUC
 WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH
WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH 
OOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH W
OD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WO
D WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOO
 WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD
WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD 
OULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD W
ULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WO
LD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOU
D A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOUL
 A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD
A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD 
 WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A
WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A 
OODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A W
ODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WO
DCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOO
CHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOOD
HUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODC
UCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCH
CK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHU
K CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUC
 CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK
CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK 
HUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK C
UCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CH
CK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHU
K IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUC
 IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK
IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK 
F A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK I
 A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF
A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF 
 WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A
WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A 
OODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A W
ODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WO
DCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOO
CHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOOD
HUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODC
UCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCH
CK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHU
K COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUC
 COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK
COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK 
OULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK C
ULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK CO
LD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COU
D CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COUL
 CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD
CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD 
HUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD C
UCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CH
CK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHU
K WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUC
 WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK
WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK 
OOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK W
OD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WO
D?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOO
?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD
```

The sorted strings are:

```
 A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD
 A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF
 CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK
 CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD
 COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK
 IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK
 MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW
 WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH
 WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK
 WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A
 WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A
 WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD
?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD
A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD 
A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF 
CH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MU
CHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOOD
CHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOOD
CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK 
CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD 
CK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHU
CK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHU
CK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHU
CK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHU
COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK 
D A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOUL
D CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COUL
D WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOO
D?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOO
DCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOO
DCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOO
F A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK I
H WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUC
HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?
HUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODC
HUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODC
HUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK C
HUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD C
IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK 
K CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUC
K COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUC
K IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUC
K WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUC
LD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOU
LD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COU
MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW 
OD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WO
OD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WO
ODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WO
ODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WO
OOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH W
OOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK W
OODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A W
OODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A W
OULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD W
OULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK C
OW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?H
UCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW M
UCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCH
UCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCH
UCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CH
UCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CH
ULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WO
ULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK CO
W MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HO
WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH 
WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK 
WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A 
WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A 
WOULD A WOODCHUCK CHUCK IF A WOODCHUCK COULD CHUCK WOOD?HOW MUCH WOOD
```

Comment: God. So close. I had most of the words but not the general concept.

Comment: Those enormous data dumps are not enlightening at all. It'd be great if you deleted them and replaced them with an explanation of how you unscrambled the message.

Comment: @Lopsy The data dumps are just to prove that the answer indeed forms the scrambled string.  I wanted to provide the same steps that the OP provided for "HELLO, WORLD!"  I did not use any techniques to get the answer.  I just looked at the scrambled string and thought it might be "HOW MUCH WOOD WOULD..." and then I verified that it was.  I'm a good Scrabble player.  :)